# Sending A/V through HDMI out, even though there is only a video device connected

Tags: sound, hardware

Basically, the HDMI Output of my computers (Mac and Windows) is only sending audio or video through the HDMI output, if a recognizable device is listed as a playback device, which I can choose.

So, for example, if I connect my PC HDMI Output of my computer to the HDMI Input of my Beamer, it is only possible to send Video data through the HDMI to the beamer, because the beamer is not recognized as an audio device(it has no speakers), only as a video device.

The problem for me is, that I would like to send both (audio and video) through the HDMI Output, even though there is no video or sound device recognized. The reason why I want to achieve that is the following:

My further TV Boxes are using HDMI output to send video/audio out. They don't care, if my beamer has audio speakers or not, nevertheless they send the audio out. So what I do is, I use this advantage and I extract the audio sound with a HDMI splitter and then I can send it to an external sound system. So it's pretty nice, I just use a HDMI switcher for all my HDMI devices and then I just select the one, which I want to use and finally, the beamer receives the video signal and the audio system the audio signal.

But, when I want to connect my PC or Mac to my current system, it only sends the video signal through it, because my beamer is recognized as a video device and it won't send audio, because it thinks, that there is no audio device on HDMI connected.

How can I solve this problem? Is there maybe a software, which can force it to send audio through the HDMI? Or maybe a mini A/V Box, which acts as a video and audio device, but it only forwards the signal?

Comment: does running `speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,3` fix it?

Comment: Do you mean this tool [speaker-test](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Speaker-test) ?

Comment: no, run the command `speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,3` in the terminal and paste the output.